# Raycast only works at a specific height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I want to make a 3D platformer for a school project.
Since I'm not that experienced in game development, I followed Plai's tutorial. My biggest problem are that I keep sliding down slopes and the slope detection. It detects the slope only if there's a surface below the slope, the player [has some distance from the ground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXM7w.png) yet is not too far from the ground.

This is the method shown to detect the slope.
Tried editing it but nothing seems to work.

```
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out slopeHit, playerHeight / 2 * 5f))
    {
        if (slopeHit.normal != Vector3.up) return true;
    }

    Color rayColor;
    if (slopeHit.collider != null) rayColor = Color.green;
    else rayColor = Color.red;

    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down, rayColor);

    return slopeHit.collider != null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in the first part

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out slopeHit, playerHeight / 2 * 5f))
{
    if (slopeHit.normal != Vector3.up) return true;
}
```

if you hit something and it is a slope you `return` already.

Otherwise you execute the rest even if you maybe wouldn't hit anything at all.

You would probably rather do e.g.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out var slopeHit, playerHeight / 2f * 5f))
{
    var isSlope = slopeHit.normal != Vector3.up;

    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, slopeHit.point, isSlope ? Color.yellow : Color.green);

    return isSlope;
}

//meaning you don't hit anything at all
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down, Color.red);
return false;
```